# Spalter Select Replacement

Tags: hops

Im going to try and brew a weissbier but my local store does not have the hops suggested to me in most recipes. What are good replacement hops for Spalter Select when brewing weissbier?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Where are you from? You could try ordering the Spalter Select online.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to go there and buy an alternative afterwork and realized that this info would fit quite well here. There are several places that provide it but I prefer to know if there are alternatives. Yet thanks for the tip! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spalt, Saaz, Tettnanger, and Hersbrucker hops are all suitable alternatives:<sup>[1](http://beerlegends.com/spalter-select-hops)</sup>

[image]

And according to another resource<sup>[2](https://www.brewps.com/hop-chart-hop-substitutes.html)</sup>, specifically U.S. Saaz and Tettnanger:

[image]